# Node.JS Heroku Postgres Connection not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server that I created using Heroku through Node.js in a local instance.
The issue I'm having is that the connection never gets established and I'm having trouble understanding why because there's no error output. The following is a snippet of my code:

```
async function main(){

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: "postgres://very_long_url_here" || process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnathorized: false
    }
});

const client = await pool.connect();
console.log('connection established.');
const currentRecord = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE email='me@aol.com'`);
console.log(currentRecord);
console.log('records pulled');
}
main();
```

When I run this script through the command line, none of the console.log() commands get printed, but I also don't get any errors back, although the connection clearly doesn't happen.
I got the connection string for the postgres database by running  **heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE**  through the heroku CLI. Very new to node, heroku, and the stack community - I appreciate any feedback you might have!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue. It turns out that I did not freeze the node version in package.json so the problem and the local/deployed behavior was caused by running the code with 2 different node versions. Locally I was running in node v10 while in heroku it was running in v14. So, doing this in package.json fixed the issue:

"engines": {
"node": "12.x"
},

Apparently, it does not work with v14, but the inmediate LTS version (12) seems to work fine. Doing a bit of research, it seems there are/have been some issues with v14 and pg [Node 14.0.0 - pg does not response #2180](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180).